# Cannot Sign in with Firebase in diferent PC - Wrong OAuth2 related configurations

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've created a firebase project on my PC and I've implemented a `Sign in with Google` it works on my PC, and when I push the project to `GitHub` and my friend makes a `git pull` when he tries to Log in the `ApiException statusCode` is 10.

### What I've tried?

I tried to add him on `firebase` on `users/permisions` as owner

I've added this `role` to my `firebase database`

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Rebuild/Clean Project

### This is the statrack

```
06-04 09:09:14.743 2546-10351/? E/FSA2_ContactsSyncAdapter: Sync has been terminated.
    bikm: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Application credential header not valid. Please fix the client to pass a valid application credential header.
        at biki.c(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):3)
        at nlw.a(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):86)
        at adpa.a(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):93)
        at adzp.b(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):14)
        at aees.a(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):4)
        at aeet.a(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):25)
        at aeev.run(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):6)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

And this

```
06-04 09:09:57.048 2546-2854/com.google.android.gms E/TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
```

My code is this, but don't focus on code, the code works ok because on my device is working.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Google sign in failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: add your friends pcs SHA-1 key in firebase consol and after that replace google-service.json file

Comment: @MilanPansuriya I have to do the keystore---- and then get the SHA-1 and then update the google-service.json? How do I put 2 SHA-1?

Comment: firebase consol  has a button ADD FINGERPRINT you can add multiple SHA-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need grab SHA fingerprints by simply running "signingReport" from Gradle Tab as shown here
[image: Get SHA Keys]

Then Add it to your Firebase project settings like this
[image: Firebase]

[image]

Comment: I am happy it helped :)